# Sending an email to all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I want to send the same email to all of the users that have signed up for my app with Rails 3. How do I do this? Where does the code go? How do I call the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something you would do from a custom rake task:

```
namespace :whatever do
  desc "Send out email to all users"
  task :mail => :environment do
    # your code goes here
  end
end
```

Then trigger the rake task via cron whenever you need, e.g. every night.

Comment: I only need to send out the email once. Also this kind of confuses me. Where would this code go?

Comment: The code would go in a Rakefile. For a one off task you can also put it in a script and use the runner to execute it.

Comment: ok... i think this will probably help me: http://media.railscasts.com/videos/066_custom_rake_tasks.mov